# Replace a string using bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have in my `package.json` file this line :

```
"version": "5.0.0",
```

And I want to replace `5.0.0` with another dynamic value. I tried like this :

```
sed -i "s%5.0.0%5.1.1%g" "package.json"
```

But is not good, because I don't know previous value that is 5.0.0. Should I write a regex here?

Comment: What happens if the string `5.0.0` appears in a different line, which is not related to _version_? You need to describe in your regex the pattern which the line to be modified must fulfil. Note also that in your attempt, a string `5X0Y0` would also be replaced by `5.1.1`, because the period matches any single character.

Comment: @user1934428 : I want to replace the content of "version". For example I have the number 100, when I run sed command I want : "version": "100"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 5.6.7 to whatever you want.
You can grep or find -exec to change many files at once.

```
sed -i -E 's/"version": "([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)",/"version": "5.6.7",/' package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [backreference](https://riptutorial.com/sed/example/8893/backreference):

```
sed -i -E 's/(^ *?"version". *)[0-9.]+(.*)/\1 5.1.1 \2/g''
```

The `\1` guarantees that the string "version" formatted the same as the input, and you don't have to retype this.

Comment: Is not working, I have in my package.json file : `5.1.1 "5.0.0"`

Comment: Right, I forgot the rest of the line. Is fixed now. I tested it with `echo '"version": 5.0.0'|sed -E 's/(^ *?"version". *)[0-9.]+(.*)/\1 5.1.1 \2/g'`

Comment: thx. Is possible somehow to specify the line ? For example search "version" in first 5 lines and replace the value

Comment: If you have a new problem, please don't ask in a comment, but post a completely new question. Stackoverflow is meant to become a searchable resource for programming problems. Therefore, the idea is to have one problem dealt with in one question, which gets exactly one accepted answer.